# How to can url/.htaccess redirect on 404 page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

When we add url/.htaccess that time display below:

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /.htaccess on this server.

So let me know how will can resolve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to access `.htaccess` file through browser?

Comment: Only Apache server must be able to read it. Visitors can not read it. `.htaccess` always `Deny from all` in Apache config file.

Comment: HTTP access to files starting with `.ht` is usually forbidden via the Apache configuration - and for good reason. It makes little sense to expose internal configuration to site visitors. There _is_ nothing to “resolve” here, everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is open your 404.php file in your theme’s folder. If it doesn’t exist, then create a blank php file. Paste the following code in there:

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");

header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));

exit();

?>
```